# Oracle drop constraint cascade equivalent in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008, cascade

In Oracle, to drop the constraint `PK_SAI` I use the syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE "SAISIE" 
    DROP CONSTRAINT "PK_SAI" CASCADE;
```

What is the equivalent of this in SQL Server?

Comment: What does "CASCADE" do when you do it in Oracle?

Comment: when the parent table' rows are deleted, it deletes the correspondant rows in the child tables, so there is no orphan data

Comment: Ok, it does the same in SQL when parent rows are deleted, but what does it do when you DROP CONSTRAINT in Oracle?

Comment: that statement.. i dont think it means what you think it means

Comment: why do you think so @mxix ?

Comment: The `cascade` option for a `drop constraint` does not delete any rows in Oracle. In simply drops any foreign key referencing the PK you are dropping. But there is no equivalent in SQL Server. You have to drop all foreign keys manually before you can drop the primary key.

Comment: Why do you need to know the equivalent (if such a thing exists) method in sql server. Can you just show us the problem you are having and what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are thinking of the CASCADE feature on FOREIGN KEY constraints, in relation to actual DELETE statements.

```
ALTER TABLE t2 add constraint FK_T2 foreign key(t_id) references t(id)
   ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Dropping a constraint with CASCADE does not delete any rows.

DELETE deletes rows, if you have enabled ON DELETE CASCADE.

Dropping the constraint simply drops the constraint (and associated indexes and dependent constraints), not data rows. In SQL Server `ALTER TABLE ...` I am not aware that there is a "CASCADE" option as in Oracle.

From Oracle docs http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm#i2103845 for the ALTER TABLE statement:

> CASCADE Specify CASCADE if you want all other integrity constraints that depend on the dropped integrity constraint to be dropped as well.